# Find a field extension $E/\mathbb{F}_7$ of degree $3$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, galois-extensions

> Find a field extension $E/\mathbb{F}_7$ of degree $3$.

Let $F=\mathbb{F}_7$.

**Option A:**

$$E=\mathbb{F}_7^3$$
where we look at the isomorphism $F\cong \{(a,0,0)\in E:a\in F\}$. But then $(0,1,0)\in E$ is not algebric in $F$ because we can't zereing it with the elements of $\{(a,0,0)\in F^3:a\in F\}$.

**Option B:**
$$E=\mathbb{F}_{343}=\mathbb{F}_{7^3}$$
But the probelm in that case is that I don't find a suitable isoomorphism such that $F"\subseteq "E$

Comment: Find an irreducible polynomial $f$ of degree three in $\Bbb F_7[X]$ and show that $\Bbb F_7[X] / (f) \simeq \Bbb F_7^3$

Comment: The $E$ in option A is not a field: $(1,0,0) (0,1,0) =(0,0,0)$. It can be considered a ring extension or a vector space.

Comment: @DonAntonio of course, I meant $\Bbb F_{7^3}$

Answer (score 2):

What is $\mathbb{F_{p^n}}$ in general? This is a splitting field of the polynomial $x^{p^n}-x\in\mathbb{F_p}[x]$. Hence it is indeed an extension of $\mathbb{F_p}$. This is the only extension of $\mathbb{F_p}$ of degree $n$ up to isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Find an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$ over $\Bbb F_7$. For instance, the polynomial function $x\mapsto x^3$ can only take the values $0,1$ and $-1$, so $f(x)=x^3+2$ has no roots and is therefore irreducible.

Step 2: $\Bbb Z_7[x]/(f(x))$ is the field you're after.

Comment: I didn't quite understand why does $$\mathbb{F}_7[x]/<x^3+2>\cong \mathbb{F}_{7^3}$$

Comment: @J.Doe Because it's a field and it has $7^3$ elements. There is only one such field (it is a known result that any two finite fields of the same order are isomorphic).